# Large prepopulated SQLite database with Appcelerator Mobile

Tags: sqlite, appcelerator-mobile

Just getting into mobile app development, and I have a couple of very basic questions relating to the use of a large prepopulated SQLite database. It's not a typical for-public-consumption app that captures a little bit of user data.

The app would be deployed to some employees of the company, not to the general public. We would like to attach their phones via USB cable to a PC and copy a 300MB SQLite db file onto their phones.

We would like to write a number of apps that know how/where to find that db file in the phone's file system, and issue selects against it. It would be read-only.

Is that scenario feasible with Appcelerator? *Can the database file be located outside the folder structure of the app so that multiple apps could use it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On both iOS and Android apps are sandboxed and can only access their own data. On Android you could use the external storage but then every app would be able to access it. Also, since on iOS the app won't be able to open the SQLite database from the read-only application resources, it will be copied to the application data directory, meaning the app will be 300+300MB in size. You better download the files once the app is installed.

Comment: Thanks for this important information. I gather we'd have to download 300MB of JSON data and "rehydrate" it into the empty database structure  included in the app deployment package?

Comment: Yes, that would be my suggestion.